# Fading images web design

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>


body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");


}
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:  #000000;
    margin-left:100px;

}

li {
    float:left;


}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;



}

li a:hover {
    background-color:  #000000;

}


img {
    position: absolute;
   margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;


}


img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;



}

            img:nth-of-type(2){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 15s linear 5s infinite;

            }
            img:nth-of-type(3){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 15s linear 5s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(4){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 15s linear 5s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(5){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 15s linear 5s infinite;
            }




            @-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{

            0% { opacity:1; } 
            17% { opacity:1; } 
            25% { opacity:0; } 
            92% { opacity:0; } 
            100% { opacity:1; }

            }
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px; // change to whatever works for you 
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.container { width: 1000px; }
.logo { 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;

}
.nav { 
  float: right; 
  width: 880px;

}


</style>

<title>Badass Burgers</title>

</head>
<body style="height:1500px">




  <img class="logo" src='logo.jpg'/>
<div class="container">


  <ul class="nav">

  <li><a class="active" href="homepage.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="info.php">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="Menu.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="book.php">Book A Table</a></li>
  <li><a href="message.php">Message Us</a></li>
</ul>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
 <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="image" src='food1.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
    <img class="image" src='Food2.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
    <img class="image" src='Food3.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
    <img class="image" src='Food4.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> hi, i am trying to fade between these 4 images for a website. so far
>   so good, however im trying to alter this code. does anyone know how to
>   alter the code such that each image changes after 5 seconds please ?
>   any help is very appriciated

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, why not just use a carousel?

Comment: im very new to css and bootstrap. can u explain pls

Comment: Take a look at the Bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). It's one of the many features Bootstrap offers that is designed to take the headache out of creating these elements.

Answer (score 0):

As litel says, the bootstrap carousel would be perfect for your example. W3 Schools have a good tutorial on Bootstrap [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp), which is what I used to build my first carousel.

But to answer your question in your present context, I think it would be much easier to do it with a short script rather than the CSS animations. I added the following code to the end of your document and that seemed to do what you were asking. Hope that helps.

```
<style>
.image-wrapper .image{
    display: none; /*Hide the images to begin with*/
}
</style>
<script>
var currentImage = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
imageChanger(); /*First image fades in on page ready*/
setInterval(imageChanger, 5000);}); /*set a timer of 5000ms for each subsequent image*/

function imageChanger(){
    $('.image-wrapper img').eq(currentImage).fadeOut();
    currentImage = (currentImage+1)%4;
    $('.image-wrapper img').eq(currentImage).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```